# Maximum number of guesses?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the maximum number of guesses it would to take to figure out a number
with the following conditions:

- The number consists of 4 digits which are chosen with *repetition* from  the set 0-9
- After each wrong guess, you find out if any of the digits in the number you guessed match a digit of the correct number at that position

Comment: If there is a match, are you told which digits match? Or are you simply told 'there is a match'?  Or could it be 'there are 2 matches'? It sounds like Mastermind!

Comment: Yes to the first question - you are told which digits match.

Comment: OK, then it is 10. After 8 tries for a specific digit it is possible you still haven't gotten it right, so there are still 2 choices left, and so for the 9th you can still guess wrong. But then for the 10th try you are certain what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only find out if a digit matches the position you asked about, you might need to try $10$ guesses.  You might as well start with $0000$.  If any match, keep them and increment the rest.  Each position is independent, so how can you do better?